# MySQL UPDATE value base on its order

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, subquery, case

I want to give a value to my row based on its `id` position but only for a certain `timestamp`.

Let's say I got a `tbl1` with `id`, `tbl2_id` `value` `timestamp` and a `tbl2` with `id` and `timestamp`. My two tables are related by `tbl2.id` = `tbl1.tbl2_id`.

First, I want to

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl1
WHERE tbl1.timestamp > tbl2.timestamp 
GROUP BY tbl2_id
```

For example,if this return me 100 rows. I want to `SET tbl1.value = 1` for row 1-10, based on the `tbl1.id` ascending order. Then, `SET tbl1.value = 2` row 11-20 and so on...

I believe that I can do this last part using `CASE`. However I'm not sure how to put all this in one `UPDATE` query.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you have a typo and really meant ***SET tbl1.value = 2 row 11-20 and so on***.

This is not tested but how about the following:

```
SET @rank=0;
UPDATE tbl1 AS mt1
  INNER JOIN 
  (
    SELECT @rank := @rank + 1 AS RowValue, st1.id
    FROM tbl1 AS st1
      INNER JOIN tbl2 AS st2 
      ON st1.Whatever = st2.Whatever
    WHERE st1.timestamp > st2.timestamp 
    GROUP BY st2.tbl2_id
  ) AS TempQ
  ON TempQ.id = mt1.id
SET mt1.value = 
  CAST(((TempQ.RowValue / 10) AS UNSIGNED) + 
  CASE WHEN TempQ.RowValue MOD 10 = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
```

In the above query the following occurs:

- tbl1.value = 1 if RowValue is less then 10
- tbl1.value = 2 if RowValue is between 10 and 20
- tbl1.value = 3 if RowValue is between 20 and 30
- etc.

I do not know how `tbl1` links to `tbl2`.  So you will have to change `st1.Whatever = st2.Whatever` to whatever is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply update across a join like this:

```
UPDATE tlb1
INNER JOIN tbl2
  ON tbl1.tbl2_id = tbl2.id
SET tbl1.value = 1
WHERE tbl21.timestamp > tbl2.timestamp
```